# GAE Receive Email and Parse it

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am wondering whether Flask app in Google App Engine Production server can receive email with attachment from gmail or any other third party.

As I am having a requirement now that I would receive a email with csv attachment, need to parse it - take the decision and change the content on the website.

I am thinking of automating the entire thing, but I do no how to setup mail with google app engine, that is my application whenever receive a mail with attachment, parse it, do the computations and change the page content and display on the website.

I have gone through google app engine document but it doesn't provide much information.

I have setup the inbound_email in app.yaml and also handlers for the email, now the only question is how to get the email to the handler script. [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api)

Is there any way on doing the above requirements ???

Comment: You have to override the InboundMailHandler's `receive` method like in this github project https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/mail/handle_incoming_email.py

Comment: yes i have implemented those but not sure whether i am able to download the attachement and parse the csv, trying it..